# Unit Test Trouble Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Tags: apex, unit-test, custom-service-console

Class

```
public with sharing class CaseCommentExtension {
    private final Case caseRec;
    public CaseComment comment {get; set;}

    public CaseCommentExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        caseRec = (Case)controller.getRecord();
        comment = new CaseComment();
        comment.parentid = caseRec.id;
    }

    public PageReference addComment() {
        insert comment;

        comment = new CaseComment();
        comment.parentid = caseRec.id;
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
private class test_caseComments {
    @isTest public static void insertComment(){

        //create test case 
        String caseSubject = 'From Case: my test';
        String caseDesc = 'my test description';
            Case c = new Case();
             c.subject= caseSubject;
             c.Description = caseDesc;
            insert c;

            System.debug(c);

            CaseComment cmt = new CaseComment();
            cmt.parentid = c.Id;
            insert cmt;

            System.debug(c.Id);
            System.debug(cmt.ParentId);  

            CaseCommentExtension.addComment(cmt);

    }
}
```

Comment: error is on which line?

Comment: The 'addComment' method doesn't take any parameters as per your definition, but in the test class it is shown to take arguments. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons you cannot call `CaseCommentExtension.addComment(cmt)`:

- The method is not `static`
- The method does not accept any parameters

So to properly test it, you need to instantiate an extension and call the method with no parameters.

```
Case record; // setup, insert, etc.
ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(record);
CaseCommentExtension extension = new CaseCommentExtension(controller);

Test.startTest();
    extension.comment = something;
    extension.addComment();
Test.stopTest();

system.assert(somethingElse, 'Message');
```

Answer (score 3):

This one is the problematic line in your Test Class -

```
CaseCommentExtension.addComment(cmt);
```

In your original class the method doesn't take any input parameters but you are passing it in your test class

```
public PageReference addComment() {
        insert comment;

        comment = new CaseComment();
        comment.parentid = caseRec.id;
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Ok perfect, thanks for the clarification. How would you approach fixing it? I cant just pass the field values as a parameter. should I just append insert cmt instead of passing it as a parameter?

Comment: Is your Apex class working as per your business requirement? If yes, then why change it for the sake of test class? Just call the method as it's defined in your class. `CaseCommentExtension.addComment();`

Comment: Sorry I wasnt meaning I would change the class. Just trying to get the test class to pass it now. Just using CaseCommentExtension.addComment(); gives me the same error.

Comment: Okay, as `addComment()` is an instance method, you can't call directly from the class, you have to instantiate the object then call your method.